# cocos2d:how to create continous parallax layer

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am creating an game in cocos 2d ,

I want to make a parallax layer that is having continuous scrolling. For example my scenario is:

---

Couple of clouds moving in back ground. As soon as it reaches the end of right screen, it should come again from left side of screen. Or some effect like never ending parallax. Any ideas please?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to create a parallax node for this,

create you cloud sprite:

```
CCSprite *blackCloud;//set it's image and position it:
//code for init
blackCloud.position = ccp(580,300);

//call selector (don't unscheduled it)
[self schedule:@selector(blackCloudMovement) interval:1/30];


-(void)blackCloudMovement
  {
    if (blackCloud.position.x == -100)
    {
        [blackCloud setPosition:ccp(580,300)];
        [blackCloud runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:6 position:ccp(-100,300)]];
    }
  }
```

Comment: i get bad access in 
    if (blackCloud.position.x == -100)

Comment: There should be some other reason for this, as it just checking position of sprite, make sure sprite is declared properly and is accessible here.

Comment: [self addchild:blackcloud]; worked...and this was lagging actually..so i used parallax and it works smooth

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve parallax in a 2D game by moving the layers at a multiple of the speed you move your camera or main character, according to their 'depth'; e.g. When player moves 1 unit of distance, layer at depth 1 moves by 0.5, layer at depth 2 moves by 0.25, layer at depth 3 moves by 0.125, etc.

Comment: Layers 'in front' of the player should move at factors > 1